# Reddit bot: random reply to comments

Tags: python, python-3.x, random, reddit, praw

This reddit bot is designed to reply using a random answer to the comments in the subreddit when the keyword *'!randomhelloworld'* is called. It replies, but always displays the same comment, unless I stop and re-run the project. How can I tweak the code so that it always displays a random comment?

```html
import praw
import random


random_answer = ['hello world 1', 'hello world 2', 'hello world 3']
QUESTIONS = ["!randomhelloworld"]
random_item = random.choice(random_answer)

def main():
    reddit = praw.Reddit(
        user_agent="johndoe",
        client_id="johndoe",
        client_secret="johndoe",
        username="johndoe",
        password="johndoe",
    )

    subreddit = reddit.subreddit("sandboxtest")
    for comment in subreddit.stream.comments():
            process_comment(comment)


def process_comment(comment):
    for question_phrase in QUESTIONS:
        if question_phrase in comment.body.lower():
         comment.reply (random_item)
        break


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like the issue is at this point of code

```
random_item = random.choice(random_answer)
.
.
.
if question_phrase in comment.body.lower():
     comment.reply(random_item)
```

You are assigning the randomized value to a variable at the beginning and using it in the below function. Hence, it is always returning the same value.

You could change it this way and try.

```
if question_phrase in comment.body.lower():
    comment.reply(random.choice(random_answer))
```

Answer (score 1):

When you start your program, you are assigning a random choice to the `random_item` once. Then you are just using that to return to each request. To make a new random choice at every request, move the random choice up to the request.

```
import praw
import random


random_answer = ['hello world 1', 'hello world 2', 'hello world 3']
QUESTIONS = ["!randomhelloworld"]

def main():
    reddit = praw.Reddit(
        user_agent="johndoe",
        client_id="johndoe",
        client_secret="johndoe",
        username="johndoe",
        password="johndoe",
    )

    subreddit = reddit.subreddit("sandboxtest")
    for comment in subreddit.stream.comments():
            process_comment(comment)


def process_comment(comment):
    for question_phrase in QUESTIONS:
        if question_phrase in comment.body.lower():
          random_item = random.choice(random_answer)
          comment.reply (random_item)
        break


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```